# Recursive function in While loop-java

Tags: java, loops, recursion, aem

I am facing an issue while iterating over the nodes in cq5.
Below is the code , after iterating the 1st level child nodes trying to iterate all the child nodes.

But once 1st level is iterated all the child nodes are not getting iterated.

```
private void findNodeWithSpace(Node node) {
    try {
        NodeIterator iterator = node.getNodes();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Node childNode = (Node) iterator.nextNode();
            if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(childNode.getName())) {
                if (childNode.getName().contains(" ")) {
                    childNode.getPath()
                    count++;
                    LOG.info("**count is**" + count);
                }
                NodeIterator iterator1 = childNode.getNodes();
                if (iterator1 != null) {
                    findNodeWithSpace(childNode);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (RepositoryException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot see a recursive function so far ...

Comment: It seems to me that this would be a "Depth-first-search" rather than a "Breadth-first-search" anyway...?

Comment: That is not recursive call. You are calling some other method (findChildNodeWithSpace), recursive means your are calling same method inside that method

Comment: Did the behavior change after your codechange?

Comment: no, I forgot to edit the code previously, still the issue is not solved.

Comment: Do you have an example input / output ? I do not see why it should break early.

Comment: You only go into recursion for nodes that have no empty node name. Do you have nodes with empty nodename?

Comment: I think if a non corrupt system there can't be nodes without a node name or an empty node name. And as MrHug mentioned I would also go the other way round. Check the node that was sent to the method and then iterate over the children which call the method recursively. And one small side note, what are you going to do with the getPath() on the childNode?

Answer (score 0):

Code seems right. If there is no empty node names, Did you check if `childNodes` has nodes to iterate over them?

Other way, I don't know about CQ5, but due to you cast to `Node` first iterator elements, maybe you also need to cast the elements of `iterator1` to `Node`, before recursion.

Comment: There is no need to cast when we do node.nextNode(). The return type is Node itself.

Answer (score 0):

**Please Refer Code Below:**

```
void yourMethod()
{
    Node mainNode = .....; // You somehow get your main node from query or hardcoding the name

   //The Recursive Function starts here. variable "count" should be instance here
    countNumberNodeWithSpaces(mainNode.getNodes());


}   



private void countNumberNodeWithSpaces(NodeIterator  nodeItr)
    {

        while(nodeItr.hasNext())
        {
            Node node =nodeItr.nextNode();


            if(node.getName().contains(" "))
            {   
                count++;

            }
            countNumberNodeWithSpaces(node.getNodes());
        }
    }
```

Comment: While OP's code has some redundancies, it should work (after correction, see edit-history). Without him giving more information about his input, I cannot see this answer as a solution to the problem, yet is an improvement.